# SQL Server - How do I update the number of child posts in a forum table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to update a column that tracks the number of "child" posts in a forum. Both Parent and child posts are stored in the same table. The schema is:

```
ForumPosts {
   PostID: bigint,
   ParentFK: bigint, -- if child, this will point to the parent
   AnswerCount: int
   ...
}
```

If the post is a child, **parentFK** points to a different record in the **ForumPosts** table.

I want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE ForumPosts 
SET AnswerCount = (
        SELECT COUNT(PostID) 
        FROM ForumPosts 
        WHERE ParentFK = ???
)
```

... but it doesn't work because the SELECT needs to reference the record being updated, which I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an *alias* in the sub query. That way, you can easily specify whether a field belongs to the sub query or to the main update query.

```
UPDATE ForumPosts 
SET AnswerCount = (
        SELECT COUNT(sub.PostID) 
        FROM ForumPosts sub
        WHERE sub.ParentFK = ForumPosts.PostID
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE f
SET f.AnswerCount = t.Counts
FROM ForumPosts f
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT ParentFk, COUNT(PostID) counts
   FROM ForumPosts
   GROUP BY ParentFK
) t ON f.PostId = t.ParentFK;
```

**However**, If these forum posts are stored as a hierarchy, in this case you can use a recursive CTE like so:

```
DECLARE @parentID INT = 1;

WITH CTE
As
(
  SELECT PostId, ParentFK
  FROM ForumPosts
  WHERE parentFK = @parentId
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.PostId, p.ParentFK
  FROM CTE c
  INNER JOIN ForumPosts p ON c.postId = p.parentFK
), WithCounts
AS
(
  SELECT ParentFk, Count(PostId) Counts
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY ParentFK
)
UPDATE f
SET f.AnswerCount = t.Counts
FROM ForumPosts f
INNER JOIN WithCounts t ON f.PostId = t.ParentFK;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9f5f/2)